# Configure MapServer 7 for both time and elevation

Tags: mapserver, wms-time

I am trying to use MapServer to serve up multi-dimensional raster data.
All the data is stored in separate TIFF images - 1 image stores (for example) air temperature at a single time and elevation.

Using the current [MapServer docs](https://mapserver.org/ogc/wms_dimension.html#supported-dimension-requests), I have a working service that uses a time dimension.  When I try to add a second dimension for elevation, no error is thrown, but the GetCapabilities request only includes the time dimension. Any other dimension I add is ignored.

My tile index postgres request:

```
NAME "time_idx"
TYPE POLYGON
DATA "geom from ms.grid_metadata using unique model using srid=4326"
```

and the layer metadata:

```
  wms_dimensionlist "time, elevation"
  wms_timeitem "time"
  wms_elevation_item "elevation"

  wms_timeextent "2018-10-20/2018-10-24/PT12H"
  wms_timedefault "2018-10-23T00:00:00Z"

  wms_elevation_extent "2, 10"
  wms_elevation_unit "meter"
  wms_elevation_default "2"
```

DEBUG level 5 does not print any error or warning output.

I currently am using the same LAYER METADATA for both the tile index and raster layers.

I tried creating a layer that includes *only* the elevation dimension.
In that case, no dimensions were advertised.

It seems I have some stupid map file problem, but I'm not seeing it.

Full disclosure: I did build MapServer from source, but this has not caused any problems so far and I have no reason to think this is my problem.

output of mapserv -v:

```
MapServer version 7.2.1 OUTPUT=PNG OUTPUT=JPEG SUPPORTS=PROJ SUPPORTS=AGG SUPPORTS=FREETYPE SUPPORTS=ICONV SUPPORTS=WMS_SERVER SUPPORTS=WFS_SERVER SUPPORTS=WCS_SERVER SUPPORTS=FASTCGI SUPPORTS=GEOS INPUT=JPEG INPUT=POSTGIS INPUT=OGR INPUT=GDAL INPUT=SHAPEFILE
```

Running on RHEL 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem.  It was a stupid typo. Use this:

```
wms_elevation_units "meter"
```

**NOT** this:

```
wms_elevation_unit "meter"
```

That one little 's' make a world of difference!